# DataContractSerializer DeSerialize Dictionary of enum (and double)

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, enums, datacontractserializer

I am trying to DeSerialize XML into an object. The object and xml looks like as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SystemData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07">
<SystemBaseMVA>100</SystemBaseMVA>
<Voltage xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfVariantdoubleM9TNTpwj>
        <d2p1:Key>Rated</d2p1:Key>
        <d2p1:Value>400</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfVariantdoubleM9TNTpwj>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfVariantdoubleM9TNTpwj>
        <d2p1:Key>Actual</d2p1:Key>
        <d2p1:Value>400</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfVariantdoubleM9TNTpwj>
</Voltage>
</SystemData>
```

The Object...

```
[DataContract]
public class SystemData
{
    private readonly double _ratedVoltage;
    private readonly double _actualVoltage;

    #region ctor
    internal SystemData(
        double systemBaseMva,
        double ratedVoltage,
        double actualVoltage)
    {
        SystemBaseMVA = systemBaseMva;
        _ratedVoltage = ratedVoltage;
        _actualVoltage = actualVoltage;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [DataMember]
    public double SystemBaseMVA { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<Variant, double> Voltage
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<Variant, double>
            {
                {Variant.Rated, _ratedVoltage},
                {Variant.Actual, _actualVoltage}
            };
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

The enum:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Variant")]
public enum Variant : int
{
    [EnumMember]
    Rated = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Actual = 2
}
```

**However when DeSerialize using following code it throws "An item with the same key has already been added."** Any idea?

```
    public static T GetObject<T>(string xml) where T : class
    {
        T obj = null;
        using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream(GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            DataContractSerializer sr2 = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            obj = (T)sr2.ReadObject(ms2);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the oldness of the question that you've already solved this, but the error message in the exception is misleading: it is possible to serialize and deserialize a dictionary keyed on an enum.  The issue is that there is no setter for the dictionary property, either private or public, on your `SystemData` class.  Thus the `DataContractSerializer` has no way to save the information back into the class.  Adding a private setter and making the fields not be read-only does the job:

```
public class SystemData
{
    private double _ratedVoltage;
    private double _actualVoltage;

    #region ctor
    internal SystemData(
        double systemBaseMva,
        double ratedVoltage,
        double actualVoltage)
    {
        SystemBaseMVA = systemBaseMva;
        _ratedVoltage = ratedVoltage;
        _actualVoltage = actualVoltage;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [DataMember]
    public double SystemBaseMVA { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<Variant, double> Voltage
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<Variant, double>
            {
                {Variant.Rated, _ratedVoltage},
                {Variant.Actual, _actualVoltage}
            };
        }
        private set
        {
            double itemValue;
            if (value.TryGetValue(Variant.Rated, out itemValue))
                _ratedVoltage = itemValue;
            if (value.TryGetValue(Variant.Actual, out itemValue))
                _actualVoltage = itemValue;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```